# Excel query execution status

Tags: sql-server, query, excel

I have inherited this huge Excel file that has a connection to the database and it will retrieve data on opening. This file is huge and it takes a long time to update (hours) and I'd like to know where in the process I am . My questions are:

1. Is there a way to see the query that is running by this Excel connection?
2. Is there a way to find out execution status, i.e. what percentage is done?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have access to the server it runs on?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Yes, I do.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure like [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) to see what's currently executing on the server, but generally there's no "percentage done" for queries. If you follow the link, there's lots of documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit [Connection properties](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-89d44137-f18d-49cf-953d-d22a2eea2d46) and retrieve the query. And perhaps disabling [backgroud refresh](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connection-properties-9d3599a9-e9b3-461d-99b2-c5505ddae6e0) you can get information about execution status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to see the query that is running by this Excel connection?

Once you've gotten Excel to finish opening the first time, you can get the query in Excel in a number of ways.  One approach is:

- Right-click on any cell in the results
- Go to the "Table" sub-menu
- Click "Edit Query"

[image: screenshot of edit query option in Excel]

You may also want to go into the "Connection Properties" withing Excel and uncheck the "Refresh data when opening the file" option if you would like to be able to open the file quickly, and then refresh the data on demand.

If you don't want to wait on Excel to finish loading results, you can get the query text using `sp_WhoIsActive` (more details on that next).

> Is there a way to find out execution status, i.e. what percentage is done?

Not exactly.  You can run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to see information about the running query (including the query text!).

One possible solution to get an "estimated progress" would be to run the query in SSMS after executing the following statement:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

This will give you the number of reads done by the query for that specific execution.  Next time the query is running, you can compare that to the "reads" column returned by `sp_WhoIsActive` to see approximately how far along you are.

This isn't an extremely reliable approach if the number of rows returned by the query changes significantly, or if various circumstances cause the execution plan for the query to change.  But if the query is stable, this could give you a general idea of how far a long the query is.